# String to Long Conversion

Tags: android, string, long-integer

I am trying to convert my string variable to a long variable. The way I am trying for conversion is:

```
try{
long SessionId =Long.valueOf(myPassword.toString()).longValue();

}catch(NumberFormatException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

While I am debugging I can see the value of "Long.valueOf(myPassword.toString()).longValue()" but when I try to see the value of "SessionId", debugger says that "SessionId cannot be resolved to a variable". What is the cause of that message ? How can I see the value of "SessionId" while in debug ?

Comment: are you accessing `SessionId` outside of your try/catch block?

Comment: Can you also post sample value that can be expected for myPassword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this:

```
 long SessionId =Long.parseLong(myPassword.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, when you step after in debugging - you go out of **try {}** and as **SessionId** was defined there it's not accessible anymore. Just place some code after it like

```
try{
  long SessionId =Long.valueOf(myPassword.toString()).longValue();
  int a = 10; // BREAKPOINT here
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and place breakpoint on it.

Comment: I agree with this answer. You should declare long SessionID before your try. Your SessioID is out of scope when you access it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 long SessionId =Long.parseLong(myPassword.toString());
```

Comment: this doesn't make any difference

Comment: I just deleted the try/catch block and changed valueOf to parseLong

Comment: yeah you are right i have also wrote same in my answer. @user2982112